# Not defined when using multi-dimensional array in javascript

Tags: javascript, arrays

I am writing a small "pacman" game in js. I am using html5 and canvas for it and it is going good. But I want to draw a map from a specification running on a multi-dimensional array. When I used a normal array it works like a charm but as soon as I use my multi dimensional array it just alerts "somthings wrong" which is sad.

I think it's because of this chunk:

```
function getMapArray() {
// define the yvalue of the map
// will be ytile later..
var items = new Array(1);
for(var i = 0; i < 2; i++) {
    items[i] = new Array(xtile);
}

items[0][0] = "0010";
items[0][1] = "0010";
items[0][2] = "0010";
items[0][3] = "0010";
items[0][4] = "0010";
items[0][5] = "0010";
items[0][6] = "0010";
items[0][7] = "0010";
items[0][8] = "0010";
items[0][9] = "0010";
items[0][10] = "0010";
items[0][11] = "0010";
items[0][12] = "0010";
items[0][13] = "0010";
items[0][14] = "0010";

return items;
}
```

But I am not sure.
It's probably somethings easy but I've been staring on the code for a long time and it says xtile is undefined even if I switch it with a integer.

Link to full source:
http://pastie.org/3168446

JsFiddle demo:
http://jsfiddle.net/928wU/

Thanks for helping!

Comment: Oh btw, when I alerts xtile it outputs 15 which is correct!

Comment: Have you tried using an array literal `[]` instead of `new Array(x)`? Avoid using `new Array`, there is no need to initialize the length of the array beforehand. And avoid globals.

Comment: And it would probably be more helpful if you'd create a http://jsfiddle.net/ demo.

Comment: I changed it, both with initialization and without. The only error was as I wrote below to the first answer :/

Comment: I've created a jsfiddle demo, didnt know about that site. Ty!
http://jsfiddle.net/928wU/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your `getMap` doesn't throw an error. It returns an Array of length 2. The first element is an Array of length max(xTile, 15), the first 15 indexes filled with all the same string. The second element is an Array of length xTile, every index is empty (undefined). I do not know whether this is desired or not.

But now, look at the code you've posted [here](http://pastie.org/3168446):

```
function drawMap(map) {
    //draw the x
    for(i = 0; i < map.length; i++) {
        entry = map[i];
        for(j = 0; j < entry.length; j++) { 
            if(i == 0 && j == 0)
                fillCanvas(map[x], x, x+40, 40, 40);
            else
                fillCanvas(map[x], x*40, i*40, (x + 1) * 40, i*40);
        }
    }
}
```

This runs through your twodimensional array. But then, it tries to receive the `x` property of your map. Wasn't `x` the width of your canvas???

Comment: Thanks, I just solved it myself acutally like 1 min ago. Didn't see your answer.

So simple mistake :/

Comment: `function drawMap(map) {
 //draw the x
 for(var i = 0; i < map.length; i++) {
  entry = map[i];
  for(var j = 0; j < entry.length; j++) { 
   if(i == 0 && j == 0)
    fillCanvas(entry[j], j, j+40, 40, 40);
   else
    fillCanvas(entry[j], j*40, i*40, (j + 1) * 40, (i + 1)*40);
  }
 }
}`

That was the correct code!

Answer (score 1):

Try using `var items = [];` (and similar for the inside ones) instead of `new Array`.

If you can get the actual error message, that would be helpful.

Comment: Woah, I switched to brackets and then the original error message disappeared but a lot like these (maybe 4, 5) came up:

Error: uncaught exception: [Exception... "prompt aborted by user"  nsresult: "0x80040111 (NS_ERROR_NOT_AVAILABLE)"  location: "JS frame :: resource:///components/nsPrompter.js :: openTabPrompt :: line 462"  data: no]

Comment: Thats maybe not relevant to my code but this for sure is:

Error: uncaught exception: [Exception... "Component returned failure code: 0x80040111 (NS_ERROR_NOT_AVAILABLE) [nsIDOMWindow.alert]"  nsresult: "0x80040111 (NS_ERROR_NOT_AVAILABLE)"  location: "JS frame :: file:///home/markus/Desktop/pacman_serious/pacman.js :: fillCanvas :: line 56"  data: no]

Comment: erm... I have never seen anything of the sort. What browser are you using?

Comment: Firefox, in Ubuntu 11.10. I think I have the latest firefox version. (9.0.1)

Comment: I will try this in Chrome and see if there's any different result!

Comment: Same result, but I don't know how to review the error there and firebug lite doesn't work on local files. :/

Comment: Strangest thing just happend, I got the code back to the original and the same error message appears. Strange since I had a different error message first..

Comment: I've narrowed it down. The problem is within the array or the creation of it.

Answer (score 0):

You initialize your array to length `1`. That's too small?

Comment: Well, he only assigns to the `0` index, so it would be fine. And anyways, the arrays will grow automatically.

Comment: I don't think so, I tried with higher values but that didn't work either. :(

Comment: He loops from `0` to `1`, that's `2` elements if I'm not mistaken?

Comment: As I said, it sets the *initial* size of the array, but the array always expands automatically, no matter what was the initial size.